# Lumen Scheduler not working using cron jobs

Tags: php, laravel, cron, lumen

i'm trying to run lumen scheduler and i have used crontab for this purpose and setup a command like this

```
* * * * * cd /home/humzayun/fbapp && ea-php71 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

before this i tried using

```
* * * * * cd /home/humzayun/fbapp && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but in log file it was throwing errors

> [2018-11-13 16:31:03] staging.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined index:
>   argv in
>   /home/humzayun/fbapp/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:53
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/humzayun/fbapp/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(53):
>
> Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}(8,
>   'Undefined index...', '/home/humzayun/...', 53, Array)
>
> ## 1 /home/humzayun/fbapp/artisan(34): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->__construct()
>
> ## 2 {main} {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: argv at
>
> /home/humzayun/fbapp/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:53)
>   [stacktrace]
>
> ## 0 /home/humzayun/fbapp/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(53):
>
> Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(8,
>   'Undefined index...', '/home/humzayun/...', 53, Array)
>
> ## 1 /home/humzayun/fbapp/artisan(34): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->__construct()
>
> ## 2 {main} "}

So after trying this all finally now my crontab is doing nothing.

my code in Kernel.php is

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use PharIo\Manifest\Email;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function (Facebook $facebook){
            \Log::info($facebook->getDefaultAccessToken());
            echo " yayy here ";
        })->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that log is reporting nothing.

but when i run this command using ssh it output 
http://prntscr.com/lhxxjq

and my lumen log file shows

http://prntscr.com/lhxy4g

But by this cron command nothing is working out like i'm doing in ssh. 
Any help will be regraded i shall be very thankful to you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll receive these `argv` errors when you're not executing the cli version of php.  You should see `(cli)` when executing `php -v`:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.1.20 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2018 10:06:40) ( NTS )
```

If you see cgi or fcgi, then you're using the wrong binary.

---

When running commands in cron, it's best not to always redirect output to /dev/null and instead collect the stderr and stdout to review for errors.  As indicated in the comments, `ea-php71` was not in the `$PATH`.  Using the full path to `ea-php71` solved the OP's problem.

Comment: Ok, so your error messages are unrelated to the `ea-php71` attempt then?   Avoid asking multiple things and including multiple problems in one question for future, but make sure `ea-php71` lives in the `$PATH` for your cronjob and look at your crond log files to check for errors.  You may consider trying to use the full path to `ea-php71` to rule out path issues.

Comment: i'm trying to do this but i can't find any cron logs. Where are cron logs ?

Comment: Depends on the OS and what cron daemon you're running.  Do you manage the server?  Do you have a sysadmin to reach out to?  You can see the output of this command by redirecting the stderr/stdout to a file instead of /dev/null.

Comment: Thanks its working fine now by using full path of ea-php71 :)

Comment: I am just using shared hosting. But still any help for exploring cron logs will be helpful for me i have set cron to send me email but i haven't got any single email

Comment: Because you're redirecting output to /dev/null..  So there's nothing to send or log here.  You won't have access to system cron logs in shared hosting.

Comment: kindly correct your answer so i can select your answer as appropriate

Comment: Updated.  The first part of the answer still applies to the error messages you included in your post.